# Managing multiple google analytics account under the same root account?

Tags: google-analytics

We are trying to enable google analytics for an android project but running into an issue with account setup. We have a single gmail account and wanted to set up separate analytics "accounts" underneath that, each with multiple properties.

Our analytics account setup: http://www.screencast.com/t/sWj7YKX4hG

The issue we are having is that the first analytics account is pre-selected (red arrow indicated here http://screencast.com/t/mILTGO4LZ) with a dropdown of that account's properties ... but we cannot select the second analytics account or any of its properties which are obviously available under the same gmail account.

Has anyone else had this problem? Did we miss a step in the config somewhere?

Comment: This isn't related to programming, so should really be in another forum, but what tool are you using there? Also, should check that your Google account has full admin rights at the ACCOUNT level.

Answer (score 0):

Log in into Google Analytics, go to Admin tab.
Click the Account drop-down.
The last option in the drop-down is "Create new account"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYPMF.png)